# Will running Windows 7 on my macbook damage its battery?

Tags: windows-7, macbook-pro

I have a 15" Macbook Pro, and I'd like to install Windows 7 on it to use it for work.

I'm aware that I'll get around 1-2 hours max running Windows on it, but one of my friends (mac maintenance guy) told me that using Windows 7 on macbook pro could damage my battery life permanently, affecting its battery life when using OSX as well.

Is this true?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: What a friend ... to give such weird "advice"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specific software will not harm your battery. How often you use it and the way you charge your battery can damage your battery.

Comment: Thanks. Could you clarify on the "how often you use it" part? do you mean if I use Windows a lot it would eventually damage my battery even if I charge it properly?

Comment: batteries wear out. The more you rely on your battery, the quicker it will wear out. When you have your laptop plugged in, the circuitry bypasses the battery and powers out of the wall directly, this of course is optimum because it will not wear out your battery as fast. If you use your laptop on the bus or airplane most often, your battery life will be much shorter.

Comment: I should also mention that usage of devices like cd-roms and higher grade graphics processors, will drain your battery faster. Hence, playing games on battery power will strain your battery more than writing a paper.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, battery life is independent of the software you run on it...

However, it does depends on how you use the computer.

- Intensively on battery?
- A lot on battery or not?
- When you recharge it?

This is different for some batteries so I guess you could best look up some battery tips on Google,
I always try to connect the power cable a lot because I tend to believe that depleting your battery is bad.

But you shouldn't worry about that,
I don't know the case for a Macbook but most laptops allow you to place a new battery when necessary.

> I'm aware that I'll get around 1-2 hours max running Windows on it, but one of my friends (mac maintenance guy) told me that using Windows 7 on macbook pro could damage my battery life permanently, affecting its battery life when using OSX as well.

People can say what they want, I would guess that it could run longer than 2 hours...
But you won't know it for sure until you try it out or have a good frined who has the same situation.